# Linux Script to Solaris

Tags: solaris, date

Hellooo!
I have the following sentence, that works on Linux, but not in Solaris Version.

```
YEAR=2019
echo $(expr '(' $(date -d $YEAR/9/30 +%s) - $(date +%s) + 86399 ')' / 86400) " days until deadline" the error is due to the date
```

Error that appears:

```
command date: illegal option -- d usage: date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS] date [-u] [+format] date -a [-]sss[.fff]
```

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are trying to use is included in GNU `date` (the default in Linux), but not in Solaris `date`.

You can install GNU date on Solaris from various third party repositories such as [OpenCSW](https://www.opencsw.org/package/coreutils/) (free) or UNIXPackages ($).

Comment: Or it may be already installed as part of the OS under `/usr/sfw/bin` (Solaris 10) or `/usr/gnu/bin` (Solaris 11).

Comment: @alanc I'll go with that. Though it's been even longer since I used Solaris than it was for the other person.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while since I've used Solaris. Last version I used was Solaris 10.
**Answer:** Solaris does not allow you to perform "date math." It does not like the *-d* option.

`man date` should show you that. There may be another option instead of -d, can't remember. Convert everything to seconds, maybe?

What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hello, the idea is to show how many days left to reach to a specific date.

Comment: So, you want to know something like:
<code>days=date(a) - date(b)</code>  
You have to code that yourself. Are you a descent scripter?

Comment: descent... i dont know what you mean. I am starter, but i will put the best to script this...

Comment: Which version of Solaris are you running?